# How to set a boolean using NSUserDefaults. Expected declaration error

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Creating a boolean to save to NSUserDefaults to see if the user has visited the application before. If they have opened the application before I want the screen to segue to the main screen.

Error:

[image: Error]

The error occurs here:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "userExists") //error here: Expected declaration
```

Here is the the logic for the rest of my code. I think it is sound, but if you see something I don't please chime in.

```
 if userDefaults.boolForKey("userExists") == true
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("moveMain", sender: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "userExists")
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where did you declare userDefaults?

Comment: At the top of the file after class declaration

Comment: That seems like a forgotten `{` or `}` somewhere or similar error.

Comment: Oh right, you are probably using`userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "userExists")` on top level of some declaration (class, struct). That code must be inside a function/method.

Comment: Ah okay I didn't know it had to be inside a function. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your comment "At the top of the file after class declaration" suggest you declared your userDefaults on top level of declaration .. avoid that  ... You need to put your code inside a method... something like viewDidLoad() or any other method

Your declaration is something like below ...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

  let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "userExists") // error...

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   }
}
```

Just put your defaults inside viewDidLoad() and it works for you...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
       userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "userExists") 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try something like :

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "abc")

There is nothing wrong with your code. May be you should clean your project and try again!!

Avoid declaring nsuserdefaults as top level declarations. Or else please share you class so that I can better let you know the reason!!